# How to only see 10 markers at a time with Google Maps API regardless of map view/zoom

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am looking to improve the Google Map in my web application. I have around 200 markers on the map, but obviously this isn't visually appealing. I was wondering if there was a way to make it possible to only show 10 markers on it based on the variable Celsius? So if the map is based on whole world view, you see the markers with the 10 highest temperature recorded. If you move to another part on the world map or if you zoom in, I would like the markers to update.

Is this possible? I tried to do this by including a max 10 markers but I cant get it to be dynamic because when I add the markers I parse through a JSON file. Which has the following output {"AA": {"celsius": 32.27777777777778, "country": "AA", "day": "25", "lat": 12.5, "lon": -70.017, "month": "03"}.

This is my last fully functioning code..

```
    // Declare map and markers array globally
    var map, markers = [];

    function initMap() {

      var myLatLng = {
        lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng,
    zoomControl: true
  });

  // Moved this out of the AJAX success and declared variable correctly
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Listen for zoom change event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    // Handle markers display
    handleMarkersDisplay();
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-cloud-calendar-project.cloudfunctions.net/InfoWindow',
    success: function(data) {

      data = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var element in data) {

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {
           lat: data[element].lat,
           lng: data[element].lon
         },
         map: map,
         title: element,
         visible: false, // Default visibility is false
         marker_celsius: data[element].celsius // Add celsius as marker property
       });

       // Push this marker to the markers array
       markers.push(marker);

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, element) {

         return function() {

           var content = 'Country: ' + data[element].country;
           content += '<br>Temperature (°C): ' + data[element].celsius;

           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }

        })(marker, element));
      }

      // All markers have been added, sort the markers array by celsius value
      markers.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.marker_celsius - a.marker_celsius;
      });

      // Handle markers display
      handleMarkersDisplay();
    }
  });
}

function handleMarkersDisplay() {

  // Check if map current zoom <= 2
  if (map.getZoom() <= 2) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 3) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 4) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 5) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 6) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 7) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 8 ) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 9) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 10) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else {

    // Zoom is greater than 3, show all markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 things:

1. Add the celsius value to each Marker object as a property
2. Add each Marker object to a markers array so you keep a reference of them

Google Maps API provides multiple [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en) that you can listen. One of them is the `zoom_changed` event. With this you can follow this logic:

1. Request data with AJAX
2. Create each Marker object and set its visibility to `false`
3. Add the celsius value as a Marker property
4. Add each Marker to the markers array

Once this is done and all markers are created:

5. Sort the markers array by celsius value
6. Check the current zoom level
7. If zoom level below *n*, loop through markers and display only *n* items
8. If zoom level above *n*, loop through markers and display them all

And repeat that logic when user changes the zoom level by listening to the `zoom_changed` event.

Working example below which will show only 10 highest celsius markers if zoom <= 2, I commented everything I changed. Zoom by one level and all of them will be displayed.

```js
// Declare map and markers array globally
var map, markers = [];

function initMap() {

  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng,
    zoomControl: true
  });
  
  // Moved this out of the AJAX success and declared variable correctly
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Listen for zoom change event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    // Handle markers display
    handleMarkersDisplay();
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-cloud-calendar-project.cloudfunctions.net/InfoWindow',
    success: function(data) {

      data = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var element in data) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: data[element].lat,
            lng: data[element].lon
          },
          map: map,
          title: element,
          visible: false, // Default visibility is false
          marker_celsius: data[element].celsius // Add celsius as marker property
        });

        // Push this marker to the markers array
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, element) {

          return function() {

            var content = 'Country: ' + data[element].country;
            content += '<br>Temperature (°C): ' + data[element].celsius;

            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }

        })(marker, element));
      }

      // All markers have been added, sort the markers array by celsius value
      markers.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.marker_celsius - a.marker_celsius;
      });

      // Handle markers display
      handleMarkersDisplay();
    }
  });
}

function handleMarkersDisplay() {

  // Check if map current zoom <= 2
  if (map.getZoom() <= 2) {

    // Loop through markers array
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      // Only show the first 10 markers
      if (i < 10) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  } else {

    // Zoom is greater than 2, show all markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Update your question with your attempt. I don't know where you placed this code and it is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Every `else if` you have added does exactly the same: it shows only the 10 markers with highest celsius value. What's the point?

Comment: At the moment if I zoom in the markers only disappear. No new markers appear to make it that there are always 10 markers in view. So if I move from zoom 2 to zoom 3, I have 8 markers insight instead of 10. I would also like the code to add markers based on the top 10 higherst temperature for that particular view. At the moment it is only removing them until the last else.

Comment: That doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve + maybe you *see* 8 markers, but there are always 10 that are visible on the map (just move around).

Comment: Anyway if you still have an issue with that, I suggest you open a new question with your current code, and a clear description of what you are trying to achieve at what zoom level, what doesn't work, etc.

Comment: MrUpsidDown, thank you very much for your help and support with this question (and my last). You are making it easier for me to learn in a time where it is difficult to contact my professors. I wanted to acknowledge that, so thanks!